# How to get columns of WebElement values outside the loop for comparison?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In below piece of code userID gives me the all column values of the current table, but when i try to use those value outside the loop for comparison to other values, it ask to create variable of colValue (though I used with List or String or WebElement) under the loop.
I need to use colValue outside the loop for comparison.

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='DataTables_Table_0']"));

for(int i = 0; i<y; i++){
    List<WebElement> allUserId = table.findElements(By.xpath("//td[1]"));
    WebElement next1= driver.findElement(By.id("DataTables_Table_0_next"));
    System.out.println("User ID = "+ userID.getText());
    // String colValue = userID.getText();
}
next1.click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Answer (score 3):

Scope of the variable is within the loop only in your case. Please read this - http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html

Declare colValue outside the for loop or do the compare the inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an array outside the scope of the loop and then store the values in it inside the loop, hence your array values wouldn't be destroyed. Later you can use the values elsewhere to get things done. Here's how -

```
String[] colValue = new String[y]; //declare the array outside the loop
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='DataTables_Table_0']"));

for(int i = 0; i<y; i++){
    List<WebElement> allUserId = table.findElements(By.xpath("//td[1]"));
    WebElement next1= driver.findElement(By.id("DataTables_Table_0_next"));
    System.out.println("User ID = "+ userID.getText());
    colValue[i] = userID.getText(); //store the values in an array so as to not loose the data in it
}
next1.click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Girish & Vinoth,
I am new to Selenium, we are just implementing it in our project. 
Answering it as
I used the code as below and it working fine where nxtValue is used as total iteration need to click on Next button where one screen gives me 10 records and so on. And ArrayList is used as import java.util.List;

```
ArrayList<String> uservalue = new ArrayList<String>();
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='DataTables_Table_0']"));

int i =0;           

for(i = 0; i<= nxtValues; i++){

       List<WebElement> allUserId = table.findElements(By.xpath("//td[1]"));

       WebElement next1= driver.findElement(By.id("DataTables_Table_0_next"));

       for (WebElement userID : allUserId){

//            System.out.println("User ID = "+userID.getText());

              uservalue.add(userID.getText());

}

next1.click();

Thread.sleep(5000);

}   

System.out.println("\nColValues: "+uservalue);
```